# Rails dynamic state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I am using the gem state_machine and want to make all states dynamic. For this I created a hash:

```
STATES = {
  :upload => {:step => 0, :text => 'Upload your file!'},
  :examination => {:step => 1, :text => 'Examine uploaded file!'},
  :download_model => {:step => 2, :text => 'Download created model!'},
  :choice => {:step => 3, :text => 'Choose different settings for your product!'},
  :payment => {:step => 4, :text => 'Pay for your product!'},
  :creation => {:step => 5, :text => 'Your product is currently assembled!'},
  :shipping => {:step => 6, :text => 'Your order was completed!'}
}
```

Now I want to iterate over the hash to create the states dynamically:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => STATES[:upload][:step] do
STATES.each_with_index do |state, index|
  state state[0].to_sym do
    def form_fields
      [state[0]]
    end

    def progress
      return {
          :step => index,
          :name => state[0][:text]
      }
    end
  end
end
end
```

After restarting my rails server I get the following error:

```
:upload state defined as Symbol, 0 defined as Fixnum; all states must be consistent
```

How can I use this hash to have dynamic states?

Comment: You most probably have a simple typo/syntax error in here. But the bigger problem is - why do you want to have "dynamic" states? Whole point of state machine is that states are clearly defined, changing states machine with existing models can lead you to invalid states!

Comment: `state_machine :state, :initial => :upload do ...` should do the trick. (instead of `state_machine :state, :initial => STATES[:upload][:step] do ...`.